# Can I configure Visual Studio Code to automatically enter ssh password?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure VSCode to enter my ssh password.

Two annoying facts about the server I log into:

1. It will always fail ("Could not establish connection to ... The VS Code Server failed to start.") multiple times whenever I try to log in the server.
2. The server doesn't allow users to use key based authentication.

In order to avoid entering password multiple times, I hope I can configure VSCode to auto-enter my password and log into the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save ssh password to vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113731/how-to-save-ssh-password-to-vscode)