# How to save ssh password to vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am using vscode to connect to a remote host. I use Remote-SSH (ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension to do so. Every time I want to connect to the remote host, I need to enter the password.

Is there a way to save the ssh password to vscode?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let's answer the OP's question first:

> How to 'save ssh password'?

Since there is no such thing as "ssh password", the answer to "how to save the remote user password" is:

This is not supported by VSCode.

VSCode proposes to [setup an SSH Agent](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent) in order to cache the *passphrase* (in case you are using an encrypted key)

But if the public key was not properly registered to the remote account `~/.ssh/authorized_key`, SSH daemon will default to the remote user credentials (username/password).

It is called `PasswordAuthentication`, often the remote user password.

And caching that password is not supported for SSH sessions.

It is only supported by a Git credential helper, when using *HTTPS* URLs.
(it defers to the OS underlying credential manager)
But I don't know of a remote user password cache when *SSH* is used.

As [Chagai Friedlander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9921564/chagai-friedlander) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113731/how-to-save-ssh-password-to-vscode/66115245#comment121696040_66115245), the answer to the original question is therefore:

> No, but you can use SSH keys and that is better.

---

Speaking of SSH keys:

"ssh password": Assuming you are referring to a ssh *passphrase*, meaning you have created an encrypted private key, then "saving the ssh password" would mean *caching that passphrase* in order to avoid entering it every time you want to access the remote host.

Check first if you can setup the `ssh-agent`, in order to cache the passphrase protecting your private key.
See "[VSCode: Setting up the SSH Agent](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent)"

This assumes you are using an SSH key, as described in "[VSCode: Connect to a remote host](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host)", and you are not using directly the remote user password.

Using an SSH key means its public key would have been registered to the remote account `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

This section is the workaround the OP ended up accepting: registering the public key on the remote user account, and caching the local private key passphrase worked.

Comment: This is still not an answer to the question 'save ssh password'.

Comment: @Alsein Yet, that is the VSCode Remote documentation proposes: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent. It will cache the ssh password, allowing you to *not* have to enter it every time you want to connect to the remote host. As asked in the question.

Comment: It caches the passphrase of a key, not a password, which is commonly known as username-password authentication and should not be confused with passphrase.

Comment: @Alsein The question is, and I am quoting: "ssh password", a colloquialism usually referring to the ssh private passphrase protecting the encrypted SSH private key. SSH-agent is the way.

Comment: I don't think a name that there is not any other alias could refer to could be taken as a 'colloquialism' to another concept. "ssh password", in common sense, is literally a password that is used while logging in to an ssh server. Although it is not recommended, there is no way to say that it could not have a name that clearly refers to it without confusion. If "ssh password" means private key passphrase, what simply means the ssh password?

Comment: @Alsein I agree with you. I have edited my answer to clearly point out my proposed (and accepted by the way) solution pertains only to a private encrypted SSH key, protected indeed by a *passphrase* (often incorrectly referred as a "password")

Comment: I think the correct answer is "no, but you can use ssh keys and that is better"

Comment: this answer is not about a ssh password. The question is clearly about saving ssh password credentials, so a user is not prompted each time. I normally would not comment but search brings this item up first in results.

Comment: @ShawnCicoria Am I right, though, to think there is no such thing as an "SSH password"? (only passphrase for private encrypted SSH key)? And no such thing as "SSH password credential"? (only a remote user credential, which the SSH protocol falls back to, when the publickey method fails, assuming the ssh daemon on the remote side allows PasswordAuthentication). I know about user credential caching when connecting with an HTTPS URL (through the Git credential helper, which defers to the OS credential manager). I don't know of an equivalent when used with SSH URL.

Comment: Still this answer is not correct.... It answers something different not the original question.
@mayank1513 How could you accept this as the answer for your question?

Comment: @OsamaFElias OK: I have edited the answer to address the origin question. The OP accepted the answer because it originally pointed out to the correct answer: use the SSH key (ie register the public key in the remote account), instead of trying to cache the remote user password.

Comment: @vonc there is a mode for ssh to accept passwords as a server challenge for credentials. It is completely disconnected from ssh key or the passphrase that protects the local private key.

https://superuser.com/questions/161609/can-someone-explain-the-passwordauthentication-in-the-etc-ssh-sshd-config-fil

Comment: @ShawnCicoria Yes, I did mention `PasswordAuthentication` in my previous comment. And caching that password does not seem supported in VSCode for SSH session.

Comment: I agree, for example Core Shell does indeed save your actual host password in the Mac OSX keychain.  Shame VScode can't do that.  It would be good.

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander the question is "HOW to save password" and your answer is "no, but.." don't you see any problem here?

Comment: Problem is I manage hundreds of websites and I dont want to setup a SSH key for every one. I have a SSH key to login to the server as root, but I dont want to use that to login to manage client websites. Before using VSCode I would use Coda by Panic. Now called Nova. Their software saves the users password to connect via SSH so you do not have to enter it every time. This is what I believed the question was asking and its not answered.

Comment: @LaurenceCope "This is what I believed the question was asking and it's not answered.": that is what I meant by "Let's answer the OP's question first: This is not supported by VSCode.": the fact VSCode does not offer a [similar feature than Nova](https://help.panic.com/nova/preferences/#keys) does not mean the OP's question is not answered. Because the OP's question is answered. And the answer is: "this is not (natively) supported".

Comment: @LaurenceCope All I have seen is the possibility to [forward your local ssh-agent to a remote](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_making-local-ssh-agent-available-on-the-remote).

Comment: @VonC yes I understand thats the answer, no problem, I only commented to say that using SSH Keys is not practical when you have hundreds of websites, it would take ages to set it all up, and sometimes you only want to access a website once and then not for years. So just wanted to point out SSH Keys are not always the answer to this question. Perhaps my comment was better suited to everyone elses answers! :)

Comment: @LaurenceCope "using SSH Keys is not practical when you have hundreds of websites, it would take ages to set it all up,": true, I fully agree with that.

Answer (score 132):

To setup password-less authentication for ssh on Visual Studio Code, perform the following steps.

These examples assume the following (replace with your actual details)

```
Host: myhost
Local User: localuser 
Remote User: remoteuser
Remote User Home Dir: remoteuserhome
SSH Port:  22
```

I'm using a Mac so Windows will be a bit different but the basics are the same

Tell VS Code and your machine in general how you will be connecting to myhost

Edit:

```
/Users/<localuser>/.ssh/config
```

Add:

```
Host <myhost>
  HostName <myhost>
  User <remoteuser>
  Port 22
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile "/Users/<localuser>/.ssh/keys/<myhost>_rsa"
```

Next generate a public and a private key with something like OpenSSL

```
ssh-keygen -q -b 2048 -P "" -f /Users/<localuser>/.ssh/keys/<myhost>_rsa -t rsa
```

This should make two files:

```
<myhost>_rsa        (private key)
<myhost>_rsa.pub    (public key)
```

The private key (<myhost>_rsa) can stay in the local  .ssh  folder

The public key (<myhost>_rsa.pub) needs to be copied to the server (<myhost>)

I did it with FTP but you can do it however you wish but it needs to end up in a similar directory on the server.

ON THE SERVER

There is a file on the server which has a list of public keys inside it.

```
 <remoteuserhome>/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If it exists already, you need to add the contents of <myhost>_rsa.pub to the end of the file.

If it does not exist you can use the <myhost>_rsa.pub and rename it to authorized_keys with permissions of 600.

If everything goes according to plan you should now be able to go into terminal and type

```
ssh <remoteuser>@<myhost>
```

and you should be in without a password.  The same will now apply in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: great answer! but no need to copy <host>_rsa.pub file, only to copy its contents and paste it on authorized_keys on the server.

Comment: This does not answer the original question.

Comment: ssh-copy-id did not add PreferredAuthentications option. added it with the help of this answer

Comment: PreferredAuthentications option only works if host allows public key auth, if it's explicitly disabled (as is the practice in some environments) you will be left SOL

Comment: "/Users/<localuser>/.ssh/<myhost>_rsa" should be "/Users/<localuser>/.ssh/keys/<myhost>_rsa"

Comment: Do you have to add these two lines 'PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile "/Users/<localuser>/.ssh/<myhost>_rsa"' to the local config file as well?

Comment: I followed the steps by 1) copying the public key to the server and changing the file name as authorized_keys, 2) adding the two line to the config file of the server, but the ssh username@host still ask for password, somehow.

Comment: This method is a bit strange, because you are creating a public/private key pair on your *local* machine, and then copying that to the server. I don't doubt that it works, however the usual procedure would be to create the public/private key on the *server* first, and then copy one half of that key pair to the machine which will be used to connect to the server. (Your local machine, or the client)

Comment: Note that the ssh daemon on the server needs to have `PubkeyAuthentication` enabled, and the `AuthorizedKeysFile` set to the correct file. This can be configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` after which you might want to restart sushi with `sudo systemd restart sshd`

Answer (score 31):

For those trying to connect through Vscode Remote SSH Extension steps provided at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_ssh-tips)

For Windows(Host) --> Linux(Remote)

1. Create an SSH .pub key in your windows  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`
2. Copy the contents of the .pub key  **(default path C:\Users\username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)**
3. SSH into Remote machine and append the contents of the pub key in authorized keys `echo "pub-key" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Maybe the best way to sidestep setting a password in vscode ssh

Comment: The easiest answer by far. In my case I already had a generated key, so I didn't overwrite and just pasted the existing one. Worked like a charm!

Comment: This worked and is a million times more straightforward than the typical answer you get given to this question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to enter your password each time you are connecting to your server, according to vs code documentation you have to:

> "Set up SSH key-based authentication to the server so you do not need to enter your password multiple times."

To do this on a Linux system (I did it on Ubuntu 22.04) :

1- Generate a key pair if you haven't already: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -b 4096`.
This would generate two files under the names: `id_ed25519` and `id_ed25519.pub`

2- Assuming that the files are saved on the `~/.ssh/` directory, use this command:
`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub user@server_ip`. You will be prompted to enter your server password. After doing so, you no longer need to enter a password to connect to your server both in the terminal and vs code.

Comment: Tried this and it still asks for my password in VSCode

Answer (score 1):

After locally configuring /.ssh/config,

On the local terminal, run:

1. > ssh-keygen
2. Keep pressing enter is fine.
3. > type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh *ip or username@hostname* "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
4. Enter your remote pswd to the prompt.

Then simply run:

5. > ssh *ip or username@hostname*
   > You're in!

Answer (score 0):

### Windows (local)

[SSH Vault for VSCode](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NH0K0H2Q5PR?hl=en-US&gl=US) (no affiliation/can't vouch)

### Mac (local)

perhaps combination of:

[SSH Config Editor](https://www.hejki.org/ssheditor/) and vscode settings:

```
remote.SSH.externalSSH_ASKPASS
remote.SSH.path
```

(will update if successful)

### Mac/Linux (remote)

[Tailscale SSH](https://tailscale.com/kb/1193/tailscale-ssh)

> This automates SSH key handling, not password entry

> not supported on windows yet